# Conver int YYYYMMDD to date pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert an INT column to a date column in Databricks with Pyspark.
The column looks like this:

```
Report_Date
20210102
20210102
20210106
20210103
20210104
```

I'm trying with CAST function

```
df = df.withColumn("Report_Date", col("Report_Date").cast(DateType()))
```

but I'm getting the below Error:

> Cannot resolve 'CAST(`Report_Date` AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast int to date;

Do you know how can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cast to string type first, then use `to_date`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Report_Date", 
    F.to_date(F.col("Report_Date").cast("string"), "yyyyMMdd")
)
```